# How can I use @SuperBuilder and @Data to be able to access a subclasses properties when it is a member of another class?

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations, lombok

Sorry, my title might be a bit confusing but I am already pretty confused my self and I am not sure how best to word it with out confusing more or using incorrect terms/concepts.

Anyways, here is my situation:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        City city = getCity();
        city.getStation().setPoliceStationName("SFPD") //ERROR?
        city.setPoliceStationName("SFPD"); //ERROR?
    }

    public static City getCity(){
        return City
            .builder()
            .station(getPoliceStation())
            .cityName("CityName")
            .build();
    }

    public static PoliceStation getPoliceStation(){
        return PoliceStation
            .builder()
            .policeStationName("NYPD")
            .build();
    }
}
```

I have another set of classes here:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class City {
    private String cityName;
    private Station station;
}

@Data
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class Station {
    private String stationName;
}

@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class PoliceStation extends Station{
    private String policeStationName;
}
```

I would like to try and be able to modify the name of the police station, but it seems that the type returned is of type Station and **not** PoliceStation. How can I go about achieving this with a setup similar to this (using lombok)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've just need to cast it like this :

```
((PoliceStation) city.getStation()).setPoliceStationName("SFPD");
```